# What is the most efficient way to place a list of drives in a ComboBox using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, combobox

I am creating a program that allows the user to select a drive letter from a combo box. I am debating between populating the box using a list or an array. What is the best and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For populating it, there is no discernible difference between a list and an array.

Personally, I would use a list as it is generally easier to use (can add/remove items, no fixed length etc.), and with generics, there is type safety just like an array. I know this has no difference in binding it to a list, but it makes it easier getting to that point.

Answer (score 3):

'Efficient' is never going to be an issue here, with a max of 26 letters.

The combobox is going to copy to an internal list anyway, so as a source you can use whatever is most convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

```
ListBox.Items.AddRange(Environment.GetLogicalDrives());
```

For the amount of drives you are going to have its hardly going to make a difference what way you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

foreach (string drive in drives)
{
    cb.Items.add(drive);
}
```